# Setting cell borders with a script throws error "Cannot find method setBorder"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, format

When I try to use "range.setBorder(true, true, true, true);" in a Sheet Script I get a "Cannot find method setBorder(boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean)" error comment.

The range is valid and works for cell coloring.

All documentation indicates my syntax is correct.  Is this a new bug or am I missing something that should be obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means "there is no method by that name that takes four boolean arguments". Which is true. There is a method that takes [6 boolean arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBorder(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean)):

```
setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal)
```

The first four describe what happens to the exterior borders of the range; the last two are about its interior borders.

If you are only doing this for one cell, then there are no interior borders, so the last two arguments don't matter - but they are required anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Totally solved my issue.That one had me really stumped for some time. Never considered a value was needed for each parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)
```